# Importing a submodule, from a sobmodule in a different package

Tags: python, python-3.x, module

I'm relatively new to Python, and I find the whole thing about import/package/modules to be way too tricky for me to understand it properly...
I have 2 big doubts, let me try to explain them with an example:

I have a Python project with this architecture (all names made up):

```
project/
    - main.py
    + data/
        - app.py
        - test.py
    + tools/
        - util.py
```

When I want to use something (let's say class `Solver`, for instance) from `util.py` in `main.py`, I import it like this:

`from tools.util import Solver`

It works fine. If I want to import something from `test.py` (function `do_it`, for example) in `app.py`, this works as well:

`from .test import do_it`

Now with the problem:

**(1) What if I want to import `Solver` from `util.py` module in `app.py`?**

I know you can have a `__init__.py` for each of the packages, where you define the functions/classes/exceptions/... you want others to be able to import from that package, but is there a way that could help me in this situation?

Also, if I do an import like this one:

`from tools.util import Solver`

it works fine when I test the things "locally", but if I install my `project` package through *pip*, I always get an error like `ImportError: No module named 'tools'`. So my second doubt is:

**(2) How to have the same import working both "locally" and after installation?**

Comment: You *must* always have a `__init__.py` in each package. It may be an empty file. Then, you can always import full module names e.g. `import tools.util`, `import data.test`

Comment: But if I install my `project` through pip, this will not work. What should I do then?

Comment: I don't know what you kind of problem you are having with pip, but you are not solving it the right way. Anyway, first things first, learn how to make modules and packages, see [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages). Think about pip later.

Comment: I have the modules and packages as in the link you just sent.
In the `main.py` I have `from data import *`, and it works just fine. But once I install my package through pip, I get the `ImportError`. However, if I switch `from data import *` to `from project.data import *`, it works after `pip install`, but it doesn't work if I try to run `main.py`